# Can I write all Spark CSS and MX CSS in one .css file?

Tags: css, apache-flex, air, adobe, flex-spark

Can I write all Spark CSS and MX CSS in one .css file?
Spark CSS : the CSS for `s:` like `s:TextInput`
MX CSS: the CSS for `mx:` like `mx:TextInput`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! More details are explained [HERE.](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_use_the_new_CSS_syntax_in_Flex_4-15726.html) Just make sure to use the correct namespaces

```
mx|Button
   {
   color:#ffffff;
   }
s|Button 
   {
   color:#000000;
   }
```

would definitely work.